# Handling extraneous characters/wildcards in d3 time format

Tags: d3.js

I want to format timestamps using d3 that look like this: `"2015-04-11T22:20:41.017Z"`. I have this much worked out: `d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%S")` but I don't know how to handle the fractional second.

I don't really care about the value- my plot is on the hours scale so just dropping it would be fine. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [formatting directive](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format) `%L` will give you the milliseconds as a decimal number. To get your desired output you could use:

```
d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,%LZ")
```

This will yield something like `2015-04-12T22:22:04,504Z`.

```js
d3.select("body>p").text(function() {
  return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,%LZ")(new Date());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>
  </p>
</body>
```